# python ssl socket OSerror An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket

Tags: python, sockets, ssl

So before anyone says its a duplicate, I have seen multiple questions with that error, but could not notice any of that being the same as my problem.

I am trying to make a small project including a socket over SSL, and when trying to catch if a user is trying to connect with a raw socket and not ssl wrapped socket (which is raising a ConnectionResetError) I get a different error.

My code:

```
import socket
from classes import ClientThread
import ssl
from time import sleep

server = 'localhost'
port = 12345
threads = []
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
context.load_cert_chain(certfile="cert.pem", keyfile="cert.pem")


with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((server, port))
    print(f"[*] server started, listening on port {port}")
    while True:
        s.listen()
        with context.wrap_socket(s, server_side=True) as ssock:
            try:
                conn, addr = ssock.accept()
                client = ClientThread(conn=conn, ip=addr[0], port=addr[1])
                client.start()
                threads.append(client)
                print(f'Threads running: {len(threads)}')

            except ConnectionResetError:
                print(f'Could not establish ssl handshake with a client.')
```

The error i get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/x/x/server.py", line 17, in <module>
    s.listen()
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

I tried setting some sleep time after the exception maybe it needed to reset the socket but didnt hlep, tried to play a bit with the placement of the While True, and while resetting the entire socket help, I dont want to reset all my clients thread just because of a client who didnt try to log in with a SSL socket.

I think it has something to do with the wrap_socket because it modified the socket instance passed to it , but couldnt find a way to unwrap.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should only call listen once, outside of the loop.

Comment: @tdelaney thanks for the reply, but than it would just accept one connection, and not be a multithread server.

Comment: No, listen just enables the socket to take incoming connection requests and sets  a limit to how many of those requests can be backlogged in the TCP stack without yet being accepted. `accept` waits for the connections to come in. You listen once and accept many times. On linux its okay (but not normal) to call listen multiple times. I assume that either Windows or the ssl stuff makes things different but can't test that.

Comment: It would be worth moving the listen outside of the while to see what happens.

Comment: yep, that works.
i was misunderstanding about what listen does, after reading the official docs i saw my mistake.
thank you @tdelaney!

Comment: I didn't see a good dup for this question so I supplied my comment as the answer. BTW, thanks for the stack trace which made it easy to spot the problem line. Its amazing how many people don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

`listen` enables a socket to take incoming connection requests (also called a "passive socket") and establishes a backlog of how many of those requests can be pending in the network stack at any given time. `accept` accepts one of those connections. You call `listen` once and `accept` many times.

Pull the `listen` outside of the `while` so that is only called once to establish this as a listening socket.